# Fury of Dracula 3rd ed. - Escape as Bat clarification

Tags: fury-of-dracula

In Fury of Dracula 3rd edition, when Dracula plays Escape as Bat combat card, and decides to move to a new location, Dracula clears his current hideout, places a new location card there along with the face-up Escape as Bat card. But what about an encounter card? Does Dracula also place an encounter card on the new location, as he normally does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, encounters are placed during the encounter phase of Dracula's turn. Moving by escaping as a bat occurs during dawn or dusk, which is outside this phase so no encounter is placed.

The first space location (where the combat was taking place) is cleared, and then the new location card - without an encounter - replaces the cleared location on the first slot on the trail.